# refresh previous page on Navigator.pop function

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to refresh the previous page/ stack when Navigator.pop(context) is called? I need to do the API calling of the previous page to refresh the state of the page. The navigator.pop will sometimes be an alert dialog or maybe a back button. Is there a way to do the API calling? ThankYou.

Answer (score 3):

use the `then` function after you push another route.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
  ),
).then(
  (value) {
    if (value) {
      //refresh here
    }
  },
);
```

and when you return to previous screen, provide the `pop` function a value that determines whether to perform some action.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

Comment: ThankYou!! what should I add in the "refresh here" section?

Comment: You can call your API and change your state.

Answer (score 0):

**Previous page**

```
void goToNextPage()async {

 var refresh = await Navigator.push(_context, new MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (BuildContext context) => new nextPage(context))
 );
if(refresh ) setState((){});

}
```

**NextPage**

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```