# Pass data to the previous screen

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app which requires data from a page to the previous page. I'm using `Navigator.pop(context)`; to exit from the current page at the same time refreshing the previous page with a function. I need to pass an ID to the previous page for an API calling. How can I pass a data by `Navigagtor.pop(context)`.

Comment: Navigator.pop(context, {"isUpdated": true});, use like this

Comment: You can get it from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030854/refresh-previous-page-on-navigator-pop-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code: `Navigator.pop(context, 'Back!');`

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
     Navigator.pop(context, 'You are old screen!');
  },
  child: const Text('Back Screen!'),
),
```

Refer [**`Return data from a screen`**](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Comment: how to collect that data from 2nd page to 1st page?

Answer (score 0):

From the First Page you can navigate to Second one. The "Navigator.push" returns a Future. Use "then" to get the value returned from Second page.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())).then((value) {

  // Handle 'value' here.
  // 'value' is returned by second page through Navigator.pop(context, 'some relevante value or object');

});
```